# Is there a way to find a value by knowing his position in the JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I'm very bad at coding, so probably this will be the most stupid question possible. I want to find a certain value in a JSON by his position in the array. The problem is that the IDs of the elements aren't sorted but they are 'random' numbers (See the photo). My question is, how can I read a certain value from an element by his position in the array? For example the ID 1001 is in position 0 etc...
If I use json['data'][1001][...] i can read separately it but it's difficult to write them using a for cicle.

The JSON is [LINK](http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.5.1/data/en_US/item.json)

```
 function myFunction() {
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/"+12.5+".1/data/en_US/item.json");
  var content = response.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ITEMS");
  var items = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var itemsPosition = Object.keys(json['data']);
  Logger.log(json['data'][1001]['name']); //works with IDs, I obtain 'Boots'
  Logger.log(json['data'][0]['name']); // doesnt work with position
  Logger.log(json['data'[0]['name']); // doesnt work
}
```

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWCLx.png)

Comment: Post **code** here, not pictures of code.

Comment: You want to get the value of every object whose ID is in the array?

Comment: If you know the position in the array, `array[position]`

Comment: @FelixKling yes

Comment: @user1599011 so will it be like json['data'[position]]?

Comment: `json['data'][position]`, but keep in mind that JSON is a string, you have to parse it first to convert to an array or object.

Comment: @user1599011 yeah I parsed it before ty

Comment: Seems like what you actually want is to get all objects in an array instead of an object. If so, just do `Object.values(json.data)`. If you only want to get a subset given a list of IDs you can use `Array#map`: `ids.map(id => json.data[id])`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Iterating through obj that came from  JSON and retrieving name values

```
function listallnames() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet name");
  const obj = JSON.parse("Your string");
  let vo = obj.data.map(o => [o.name]);
  sh.getRange(1,1,vo.length,vo[0].length).setValues(vo):
}
```